# Cannot find a mistake

Tags: python

The following code:

```
s = 0

M =3

for i in range(M):
    s += 1/2*k**2

print(s)
```

should compute this sum:

[image: 1]

But there are three errors that lead to a wrong answer.

I have found two errors: k is not defined, and there should be a parentheses around 2*k. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: `k is not defined`, right what is `k`?

Comment: do you have what the equation is you're trying to find written mathematically rather than in code? it's difficult to know what's wrong when we're not sure what you're trying to achieve

Comment: It should be `for k in range(1, M+1):`. Indexes in Python  run from zero so `range(M)` gives 0,1,2 and I think you want `1,2,3`.

Comment: The bounds of your range are wrong. I think you want `range(1, M+1)`.

Comment: I thought i posted a picture  with the mathematical equation but maybe not. I am trying to compute the sum for 1/(2*k^2) for k=1 and with range 3.

Comment: @NicolaiAakerMenken it has been added to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your for loop, you need to have `for k in range` rather than i so k changes with each loop (this will  fix the k is not defined issue). You were  missing a set of brackets on your denominator, as you pointed out. You also need to have `range(1, M+1)` as python starts ranging from 0 automatically, and doesn't include the upper bound, hence you need to shift the range by 1.

```
s = 0
M = 3
for k in range(1, M+1):
        s += 1/(2*k)**2
    
print(s)
```

Comment: `1/(2*k)**2` is sufficient parentheses.

Comment: @khelwood so it is! I'm sometimes a bit overkill with brackets. Have edited

Answer (score 0):

```
s = 0
M = 3
for k in range(1, M+1):
        s += 1/((2*k)**2)
    
print(s)
```

So, the beginning You have to declare some variables: s for storing result and M as your range to loop. In for loop k is iter variable and increases every loop. k starts from 1 and increasing to M, because range function returns [n, m) interval.

Comment: The question posed is "What are the mistakes in the code?"

Comment: `1/2*k**2` means `(1/2) * (k**2)`, which is wrong.

Comment: So, the beginning You have to declare some variables: `s` for storing result and `M` as your range to loop. In for loop `k` is iter variable and increases every loop. `k` starts from 1 and increasing to M, because `range` function returns  [n, m) interval.

Comment: Explain in your post, not in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

It was happened because k haven't declare before use. Also no need to use another variable like k.You can use parentheses to change the operating order of math formula. You can use i with simple edit on for loop.

```
s = 0
M =3

for i in range(1,4): # i = 1 , 2 , 3
    s += 1/(2*i)**2

print(s)
```

Comment: `(2*i**2)` is different from `(2*i)**2`.

Comment: True, Also I am bad on maths  too. :)

Comment: Yes. Thanks for mentioning it. I updated the code.